# Kivy installation error in Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, kivy

I installed python-dev , libglu-dev and libevent-dev packages on Ubuntu 12.04, but when I tried to install kivy from sudo python setup.py install it throws me the following error.

```
      Error compiling Cython file:
     -----------------------------------------------------------
   .    ..
          glDeleteFramebuffers(len(self.lr_fbo_fb), arr.data.as_uints)
         del self.lr_fbo_fb[:]
     if len(self.lr_fbo_rb):
         Logger.trace('Context: releasing %d renderbuffer fbos' % len(self.lr_fbo_fb))
         arr = self.lr_fbo_rb
         glDeleteRenderbuffers(len(self.lr_fbo_rb), arr.data.as_uints)
                                                           ^
```

---

```
 kivy/graphics/context.pyx:303:63: Cannot convert Python object to 'GLuint *'
building 'kivy.graphics.context' extension
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes     -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c kivy/graphics/context.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7   /kivy/graphics/context.o
 kivy/graphics/context.c:1:2: error: #error Do not use this file, it is the result    of       failed Cython compilation.
```

I will be very happy if any one can give me what to do. I tried everything. Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is better suited at [ask.ubuntu.com](http://ask.ubuntu.com). You should also follow the [installation guide](http://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-linux.html#using-software-packages) which lists all pre-requisite packages that need to be installed before you can compile the framework. This type of question isn't suited for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can install kivy in ubuntu with PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kivy-team/kivy
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-kivy
```

PPA Home Page: https://launchpad.net/~kivy-team/+archive/kivy

As the PPA description section says, this is the reason you fail:

> NOTICE: We may have Cython packages uploaded here, but don't give any guarantee that these are working! We just have them hosted there because of build problems with Cython older than 0.18.0.